# What will be the endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, cors, coinmarketcap

I'm trying to run a code on react that do some crypto currency conversion. I'm having some problems with CORS as I call the coinmarketcap API. I'm trying to solve it using http proxy middleware, so I do have this file called setupProxy.js which is like this:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

and the `useEffect` to call the API through axios is like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  const apiKey = 'wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww';
  const url = ` https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?name`;
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "true"
      },
    });
```

Also I put   "proxy":"http://localhost:3000" on package.json. This is not working, the dropdown doesn't show the list of coins and the console shows me this:

> Pedido de origem cruzada bloqueado: A política de mesma origem não permite a leitura do recurso remoto em https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?name. (Motivo: cabeçalho CORS ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ em falta). Código de estado: 200.

Which is in Portuguese and it says that header CORS ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Call the API of coinmarket to show a list of currencies in a dropdown.

UPDATE:
now I have a file called server.js, which is like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());

// API endpoint to fetch data from CoinMarketCap
app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  const apiKey = 'wwwwwwwwwwwwww';
  const fromCurrency = req.query.from;
  const toCurrency = req.query.to;
  const url = `http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=${fromCurrency}&convert=${toCurrency}`;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "true"
      },
    });
    const data = response.data.data[fromCurrency];
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data from CoinMarketCap:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch data from CoinMarketCap' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

and app.js:

`````
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import { HiSwitchHorizontal } from 'react-icons/hi';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const [input, setInput] = useState(0);
  const [from, setFrom] = useState('USD');
  const [to, setTo] = useState('BTC');
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const [output, setOutput] = useState(0);
   
// useEffect não vai existir após a requisição ser feita via back-end
useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch data from your backend API
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(`/api/currency?from=${from}&to=${to}`);
      const data = response.data;
      setInfo(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data from backend:', error);
    }
  };

    fetchData();
      
      
  }, [from, to]);
//talvez seja possível manter esse useEffect e o seguinte. o object.keys pega quais chaves?
  useEffect(() => {
    const availableOptions = Object.keys(info);
    setOptions(availableOptions);
  }, [info]);


  function convert() {
    const fromRate = info[from]?.quote?.USD?.price || 0;
    const toRate = info[to]?.quote?.USD?.price || 0;
    const convertedAmount = (input / fromRate) * toRate;
    setOutput(convertedAmount);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    convert();
  }, [input, from, to]);


  function flip() {
    const temp = from;
    setFrom(to);
    setTo(temp);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>Currency converter</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="left">
          <h3>Amount</h3>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter the amount"
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="middle">
          <h3>From</h3>
          <Dropdown
            options={options}
            onChange={(e) => setFrom(e.value)}
            value={from}
            placeholder="From"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="switch">
          <HiSwitchHorizontal size="30px" onClick={() => flip()} />
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h3>To</h3>
          <Dropdown
            options={options}
            onChange={(e) => setTo(e.value)}
            value={to}
            placeholder="To"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="result">
        <button onClick={() => convert()}>Convert</button>
        <h2>Converted Amount:</h2>
        <p>
          {input} {from} = {output.toFixed(2)} {to}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
````

now it seems that CORS is all right, I've also setted proxy to   "proxy":  "http://127.0.0.1:5000" on package.json. Now on console it shows 404 error, the url is not found. the get is like this: GET
http://192.168.1.106:3000/api/currency?from=USD&to=BTC

what am I doing wrong? why the url is like this?
`````

Answer (score 0):

The coinmarketcap.com website does not allow you to make requests to the their site from another domain. This is prevented via Cross-Origin headers.

You can read more about how CORS works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: so what can I do? I cannot use it at all?

Comment: anyway, even if I try to call another api, am I doing right the configurations and the call on useeffect?